# Firefox SSH tunnel per tab

Tags: firefox, proxy, firefox-extensions, ssh-tunnel

I'd like to be able to set up a SSH tunnel to browse the web on each tab. In Chrome there is a plugin called `TunnelSwitch` which lets you set up multiple proxies and you can toggle through them with a simple click on each tab.

Is this possible on firefox? I haven't found any plugin to do this so I started thinking it might not be possible.

If not possible per tab, is it possible per window?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This firefox extension (or its siblings): https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/ allows you to do pretty complicated setup and specify a different proxy per tab, as you can have an icon that toggles which proxy you are using.

It is powerful and complicated so you can shoot yourself, but that could also solve your problem.

Here is a copy and paste of its description:

WHAT IS IT?
FoxyProxy is a Firefox extension which automatically switches an internet connection across one or more proxy servers based on URL patterns. Put simply, FoxyProxy automates the manual process of editing Firefox's Connection Settings dialog. Proxy server switching occurs based on the loading URL and the switching rules you define.

```
Switch proxies with URL pattern matching
Custom colors make it easy to see which proxy is in use
Advanced logging shows you which proxies were used and when
Automatically synchronize all of your proxy settings with your other Firefox instances when you use Firefox Sync. Import/Export settings to files when not using Firefox Sync
```

Comment: I haven't been able to manage it per tab. If i change the proxy from the icon it changes for all tabs. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I do not remember 100% when I used it, but I think it was per tab. Try maybe the advanced version? Or if you can rely on the URL pattern matching. Another solution would be to use different firefox profiles but that may be inconvenient depending on the workload. Maybe also have a look at "Firefox Multi-Account Containers" Mozilla extension, as it is capable of segregating cookies per containers, so maybe proxy settings too?

Comment: FoxyProxy toggle is global, not per tab nor per window. I believe I've installed the advanced version, the one called `Standard` that you linked. I've thought about different profiles but it doesn't really convince me. I'll try `Firefox Multi-Account Containers` but it doesn't seem to handle proxy settings =(

Comment: I am sorry for the false lead then, and I have no further ideas for now :-(